# Spring boot deploy wildfly doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, joinfaces

I'm trying to deploy an application on wildfly server made in springboot. I'm generating a war file with `mvn clean install` and put on wildfly through administrator console, but the application doesn't start.

I suspect that the error could be joinfaces, because I start another simple hello world application without joinfaces and the application works fine.

Here's my SpringApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class AudicontasApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-3"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AudicontasApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(AudicontasApplication.class);
}
}

class CustomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.status("I <3 Production!").build();
    }
}
```

Here's my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.techlead.audicontas</groupId>
    <artifactId>audicontas</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>audicontas</name>
    <description>Projeto com as regras de negócio e os serviços do sistema audicontas.</description>
    <!-- <url>https://www.codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-example-spring-boot-maven.html</url> -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <!--<version>3.1.0</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQL server Driver JDBC-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- joinfaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.stella</groupId>
            <artifactId>caelum-stella-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.theme</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's Wildfly log error:

```
11:18:52,580 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:44)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:118)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:99)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more

11:18:52,587 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 5) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "audicontas-1.0.0.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
11:18:52,588 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 5) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "audicontas-1.0.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that joinfaces pulls in the `tomcat-jasper` library. You'll have to go read the pom to confirm though.

Comment: Why are you taking out the tomcat dependencies and also what embedded webserver are you adding in its place? I don't see one so perhaps it's better to remove the tomcat exclusions until you get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best option, but for me this problem was solved when I remove the jar dependency `tomcat-embed-jasper`. I've just inserted the code below in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the tomcat related dependencies and excluded the embedded tomcat. And then generated war and it is working with wildfly

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)